# Return values from multiple rows across multiple sheets, using the same identifier

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I have come across this problem often and I am hoping there is an efficient solution for this, one that I can replicate. I typically need to summarize data contained in multiple sheets of a excel (2016 or 365) or googlesheet. I create a report by adding a tab within the workbook. To generate the report, I use formulas to pull in some of the values contained in each sheet. Vlookups or Hlookups work for most use cases but only returns the first value using a unique identifier that is present in the report tab and in the other sheets. Where I run into issues is when I would like to return multiple values from a unique identifier. For context, I typically need each column of the report tab to pull in values from one column of another sheet. The tabs typically contain 1000s of rows so an efficient formula would. Any tips?

Comment: Edit your question to include the version of Excel you are using as well as a sample of your data.  The newer versions of Excel have advanced features that make this sort of task trivial.

Comment: @CSGrant `FILTER()` formula will work on **Excel-365**.

Comment: I think this question is too broad - please give us some specific examples